# Sum of series : $1+11+111+...$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Sum of series $1+11+111+\cdots+11\cdots11$  ($n$ digits)

We have:

$1=\frac {10-1}9,$

$11=\frac {10^2-1}9$

.

.

.

$11...11= \frac {10^n-1}9$ (number with $n$ digits)

and summing them we find the sum ($S$) as:

$S=(10^{n+1}-9n-10)/81$

Also the general form of terms is:

$s(n)=(10^{n+1}-10^n-9)/81$

Now consider the function:

$f(x)=10^{x+1}−10^x-9$

Since $\Delta x= 1$, due to definition of integral we can write:

$S=(1/81)\sum (10^{x+1}−10^x-9), [1, ∞]$

$ =(1/81)∫(10^{x+1}-10^x-9) dx ;[0, 1]$

but it does not work. **Can someone say what went wrong, i.e, Why doesn't the integral give $S$ as I mentioned first?**

I realized now that this is more a sequence rather than a series. A sequence is 
a set of numbers which are resulted from a general term where as a series is a 
set of functional elements; the derivative of elements of a sequence is zero and 
its integration is pointless. So using the integration of general term of a 
sequence to find its sum is just not needed.

Comment: I would like to continue my answer, but I think there is a syntax error in your integral. Note, a little bit of latex knowledge would be useful to learn.

Comment: An integral is not a sum. Sometimes one can express (the asympotic of) a sum as a Riemann sum, and hence reduce it to an integral. You cannot do that here.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not entirely sure how you went from the summation notation to the integral notation, changing the bounds when you did.

Comment: This is [arithmetico-geometric](https://www.google.com/search?q=arithmetico+geometric) series (progression, sequence). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence) or [AoPS](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetico-geometric_series). You can find a very similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024158/how-to-find-a-general-sum-formula-for-the-series-5555555555).

Comment: Why is this question tagged 'geometric topology'?

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck That was [my mistake](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1946906/revisions). Since the question is about arithmetico-geometric progression, both (arithmetic-progression) and (geometric-progression) seemed like reasonable tags (see also [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/9/30)). I simply clicked on the wrong tag. If you see an incorrectly tagged question, do not hesitate and edit the tags.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{i=1}^n (10^i-1)/9 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{9} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n 10^i - \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \right) \\[6pt]
&=  \frac{1}{9} \left(\frac{10}{9}(10^n -1) - n\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{10}{81} (10^n -1) - \frac{n}{9}
\end{align*}
$$